# Woocommerce not displaying reviews

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been making a Wordpress site with Woocommerce so that users may be able to buy items.

My problem is that the comments/reviews aren't showing up for individual items. It only shows up if I turn on template debug mode. Otherwise, I've been making sure wordpress has comments turned on, I've copied the woocommerce plugin templates over to my theme to override, and that each item has comments turned on as well, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: If it works in template debug mode, then the issue is presumably in your theme's templates. Specifically check the `single-product-reviews.php` template and compare it to the default.

Comment: add site url for help